# Creating a dropdown with a custom input field

Tags: php, shell

I've written the code below as a text input, but ideally I'd like to have a dropdown menu with options for bin/bash, zsh, and custom. If a custom input is chosen, the user should be able to input their login shell as a text input. Any help is welcome!

```
<?php
echo "<h5>Login Shell</h5>";
echo
"<div class='inline'>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='form_type' value='loginshell'>
<input type='text' name='loginshell' placeholder='Login Shell (ie. /bin/bash)' 
value=" . $USER->getLoginShell() . " required>
<input type='submit' value='Set Login Shell'>
</form>
</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<select>` element and show/hide the text input when (event `change`) the value is right.

```js
document.querySelector("#choose").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var textarea = document.querySelector("#custom-text");
  if (this.value == 'custom') {
    textarea.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    textarea.style.display = 'none';
  }

})
```

```html
<p>Please select a version
</p>
<select id="choose">
  <option>bin/bash</option>
  <option>zsh</option>
  <option>custom</option>
</select>
<br>

<input id="custom-text" placeholder="type your choice" style="display: none;">
```